# Loop and lookup several rows in another table in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have two dataframes, 
table 1: user purchased item on day 0
table 2: price of item over x days (fluctuates day to day)

I want to match when the user purchase the price to the item. Is there a better way to do this without looping every row then apply a function?

My final output is I want to know what is the rolling_average 3 day average for apples when john bought it on 1/1?

First Table:
John's Table (there could be more user)

```
Date    Item    Price
1/1/2018    Apple   1
2/14/2018   Grapes  1.99
1/25/2018   Pineapple   1.5
5/25/2018   Apple   0.98
```

Reference Table: Price Table

```
Date    Item    Price
1/1/2018    Apple   1
1/2/2018    Apple   0.98
1/3/2018    Apple   0.88
1/4/2018    Apple   1.2
1/5/2018    Apple   1.3
1/6/2018    Apple   1.5
1/7/2018    Apple   1.05
1/8/2018    Apple   1.025
2/10/2018   Grapes  3.10
2/11/2018   Grapes  0.10
2/12/2018   Grapes  5.00
2/13/2018   Grapes  0.40
2/14/2018   Grapes  1.00
2/15/2018   Grapes  2.70
2/16/2018   Grapes  0.40
2/17/2018   Grapes  0.40
1/23/2018   Pineapple   0.50
1/24/2018   Pineapple   0.60
1/25/2018   Pineapple   0.70
1/26/2018   Pineapple   0.60
1/27/2018   Pineapple   0.60
1/28/2018   Pineapple   0.50
1/29/2018   Pineapple   0.70
1/30/2018   Pineapple   0.50
5/21/2018   Apple   7.00
5/22/2018   Apple   6.00
5/23/2018   Apple   5.00
5/24/2018   Apple   6.00
5/25/2018   Apple   5.00
```

Example for Apple:

```
Date    Item    Price       
1/1/2018    Apple   1       #bought on this date
1/2/2018    Apple   0.98    #so next 3 days
1/3/2018    Apple   0.88    0.953333333
1/4/2018    Apple   1.2     1.02
1/5/2018    Apple   1.3     1.126666667
1/6/2018    Apple   1.5     1.333333333
1/7/2018    Apple   1.05    1.283333333
1/8/2018    Apple   1.025   1.191666667

df_price.withColumn('rolling_Average', f.avg("Price").over(Window.partitionBy(f.window("Date", "3 days"))))
```

Comment: So it looks like you are calculating the 3-day rolling average and setting it as a new column? What is your final desired output for John? How do you want to handle the fact that `Apple` appears again starting in May?

Comment: @rahlf23 I figured perhaps store it in a new temporary table, so that apple can be shown again but at a different date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if I understand problem correctly, you want to calculate 3 days average for each item. Then you need simply join table 1 to table 2 to get only sold items with their average price next to actual price.
You can do this by using window function.
In pyspark it can be something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df_price = df_price.withColumn(
    'rolling_average',
    F.avg(df_price.price).over(
        Window.partitionBy(df_price.item).orderBy(
            df_price.date.desc()
        ).rowsBetween(0, 3)
    )
)
```

Then you simply do join your table to result of this.
In SQL it would be like this:

```
WITH b as (
SELECT '1/1/2018' as date_p,  'Apple' as item, 1 as price
UNION ALL SELECT '1/2/2018' as date_p,  'Apple' as item, 0.98 as price
UNION ALL SELECT '1/3/2018' as date_p,  'Apple' as item, 0.88 as price
UNION ALL SELECT '1/4/2018' as date_p,  'Apple' as item, 1.2 as price
UNION ALL SELECT '1/5/2018' as date_p,  'Apple' as item, 1.3 as price
UNION ALL SELECT '1/6/2018' as date_p,  'Apple' as item, 1.5 as price
UNION ALL SELECT '1/7/2018' as date_p,  'Apple' as item, 1.05 as price
UNION ALL SELECT '1/8/2018' as date_p,  'Apple' as item, 1.025 as price
UNION ALL SELECT '2/10/2018' as date_p, 'Grape' as item, 3.10 as price)
SELECT *, AVG(price) OVER (
  PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date_p DESC
  ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING
) from b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to group by a specific item (setting your Price Table to `df2`):

```
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2 = df2.set_index('Date')

df2['Rolling'] = df2[df2['Item']=='Apple']['Price'].rolling(3).mean()
```

Printing `df2[df2['Item']=='Apple']` will yield:

```
             Item  Price   Rolling
Date                              
2018-01-01  Apple  1.000       NaN
2018-01-02  Apple  0.980       NaN
2018-01-03  Apple  0.880  0.953333
2018-01-04  Apple  1.200  1.020000
2018-01-05  Apple  1.300  1.126667
2018-01-06  Apple  1.500  1.333333
2018-01-07  Apple  1.050  1.283333
2018-01-08  Apple  1.025  1.191667
2018-05-21  Apple  7.000  3.025000
2018-05-22  Apple  6.000  4.675000
2018-05-23  Apple  5.000  6.000000
2018-05-24  Apple  6.000  5.666667
2018-05-25  Apple  5.000  5.333333
```

The answer is slightly different if you want to restrict to certain date groupings.

Comment: but you'd still need to loop over table 1 to find what user bought and what date

Comment: So how are you using that information then? You want to use the item that the user purchased, as well as the date of the purchase, and then return the 3-day moving average of that item on that date from the Price Table?